# In the First Fundamental Theorem of Calculus, why must $F : [a, b] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be continuous at the interval endpoints?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

> Show that the First Fundamental Theorem (Integrating Derivatives) it is necessary to assume that the function $F : [a, b] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is continuous at the endpoints of the interval.

I'm aware that in the last step of the proof, when the Mean Value Theorem is applied on each subinterval $[x_{i - 1}, x_{i}]$ for $i\geq1$, it is required that $F(x)$ is continuous at each subinterval $[x_{i - 1}, x_{i}]$ for $i \geq 1$, so taking $x_{0} = a$ and $x_{n} = b$ suffices.  But does this explanation really suffice for this question? Since the question says "show," I think it would be better for me to show where it breaks down, but I haven't been able to do that.

For reference, the First Fundamental Theorem states that if the function $F' : (a, b) \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is both continuous and bounded, then,

$$\int_{a}^{b} F'(x) \mathop{dx} = F(b) - F(a)$$

Comment: Intuitively, I see that you use $F(b)$ and $F(a)$ on the RHS of the statement of the FFT, so they cannot admit arbitrary values.

Comment: I don't understand what the issue is if $F(b)$ and $F(a)$ are defined but $F$ isn't continuous there, though?

Comment: Assume that $F(x)=x$ for $x \in (3,4)$ and that $F(3)=10000$ and $F(4)=5000$. Now assume again that $F$ is above but $F(3)=-59$ and $F(4)=e^3$. The point is (intuitively) that if you do not tie the values at the edges then the RHS of the statement of the Theorem can take an arbitrary value.

Comment: @JimmyR.: at the same time if you increase the value of $F(a), F(b) $ by same amount then $F(b) - F(a) $ remains unchanged and $F$ can become discontinuous at $a, b$. Under the condition that $F'$ is bounded and continuous on $(a, b) $ we can only ensure that $\lim_{x\to a^{+}} F(x)=A, \lim_{x\to b^{-}} F(x) =B$ exist and $\int_{a} ^{b} F'(x) \, dx=B-A$. See details in my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Updated: 11/8/18]

> [**Statement A from OP**] *For reference, the First Fundamental Theorem states that if the function $F' : (a, b) \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is both continuous and bounded, then,* 
>   $$
> \int_{a}^{b} F'(x) \mathop{dx} = F(b) - F(a)\tag{1}
> $$

This cited "First Fundamental Theorem" is **incorrect**. Consider the following simple counterexample. Let $F:[0,1]\to{\mathbb R}$ be such that $F(x)=0$ on $[0,1)$ and $F(1)=1$. Note that $F':(0,1)\to{\mathbb R}$ is both continuous and bounded **but**
$$
\int_0^1F(x)\ dx=0\neq F(1)-F(0).
$$

- Now, in order to turn A into a correct statement, must one assume that $F$ is continuous at both the endpoints $a$ and $b$?

  No, since one can simply consider the example of $F:[0,1]\to{\mathbb R}$ where $F(x)=0$ for $x\in(0,1)$ and $F(0)=F(1)=1$.
- What assumption of $F$ can one add to the statement A so that one can conclude (1)?

  [Theorem 7.34](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2zeIf.png) (Second fundamental theorem of integral calculus) in Apostol's *Mathematical Analysis* (2nd edition 1974, page 162) states the following:

  > Assume that $f\in{\mathbb R}$ on $[a,b]$. Let $g$ be a function defined on $[a,b]$ such that the derivative $g'$ exists in $(a,b)$ and has the value
  >   $$
  > g'(x)=f(x)\quad \forall x\in(a,b).
  > $$
  >   At the endpoints assume that $g(a+)$ and $g(b-)$ exist and satisfy
  >   $$
  > g(a)-g(a+)=g(b)-g(b-).
  > $$
  >   Then we have
  >   $$
  > \int_a^bf(x)\ dx = \int_a^b g'(x)\ dx= g(b)-g(a).
  > $$
- Also, see [Paramanand Singh's answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2988141/587192).

---

[The following original answer is based on an "incorrect" assumption that the statement A cited by OP is correct, which is not.]

Your cited version of FTC is usually called the [*second* fundamental theorem of calculus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_calculus#Second_part) in references.

For necessity, note that your version of FTC implies that
$$
\int_a^xF'(t)\ dt=F(x)-F(a),\quad x\in [a,b],
$$
equivalently,
$$
F(x)=F(a)+\int_a^xF'(t)\ dt\quad x\in [a,b].
$$
Since the map
$$
x\mapsto \int_a^xF'(t)\ dt
$$
is continuous on $[a,b]$ by the [first fundamental theorem of calculus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_calculus#First_part), $F$ must be continuous on $[a,b]$ as well. In particular, $F$ is continuous at both $x=a$ and $x=b$.

Comment: You can increase $F(a), F(b) $ by same amount and make $F$ discontinuous. Continuity at end points is not guaranteed by the conditions of the theorem (at least as discussed in question) .

Comment: Well, it also took me a little more time to fully comprehend the problem and then I updated my answer.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh: I have a second thought about this: in the statement of the "theorem" in OP, there are not quantifiers for $a$ and $b$. Usually, in real analysis, such general statement means it is true for all $a,b\in{\mathbb R}$ with $a<b$. (Lots of theorems begin with something like "Let $[a,b]$ be a compact interval ...") Then for given $a<b$, it is also true for the interval $[a,x]$ for *any* $x$ with $a<x<b$ and hence $\int_a^xF'(t)\ dt=F(x)-F(a)$. I think this should prevent examples such as $F(x)=0$ on $(0,1)$ and $F(0)=F(1)=1$.

Comment: the idea is that if you take intermediate points then you already know that derivative $F'$ exists at those points and is continuous too. I wanted to examine what happens at the end points of the interval where we don't have any given information.

Comment: I have asked a follow up question https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2989470/72031 you may have a look.

Comment: Also note that the result for $[a, x] $ is implied by applying the theorem on interval $[a, x] $ but the process can't be reversed. If something holds for $[a, x] $ for all $x\in(a, b) $ it does not necessarily mean that the result holds for $[a, b] $.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh: hmm, I think it is the other way around: first all, this theorem is true for $a,b\in{\mathbb{R}}$: for any given $a<b$, we have the *implication* that $F'$ being bounded and continuous on $(a,b)$ implies the identity $\int_a^bF'(x)\ dx=F(b)-F(a)$.  Now for any given $a,b$ and $F'$ being bounded and continuous on $(a,b)$, the theorem says that the result holds for $[a,b]$. But since $F'$ is automatically bounded and continuous on $(a,x)$ as well for given $x\in (a,b)$ the results holds for $[a,x]$.

Comment: My point is this: you are correct that "$F'$ being bounded and continuous on $(a,b)$" (the *assumption* of the cited theorem) **does not** implies that $F$ must be continuous at the endpoints. However, the cited theorem itself does. The difference between the assumption of the cited theorem and theorem itself is that the theorem is of the form $p\to q$ while the assumption is $p$ alone. If one denotes $F$ being continuous at the endpoints as the statement $r$, then $(p\to q)\to r$ but $p\not\to r$.

Comment: The conditions of the theorem are such that $a, b, F$ are fixed and the behavior of $F$ is known only in th e interior of $[a, b] $ and not at end points. The question specifically asks if we need continuity of $F$ at $a, b$ or not. The issue in your approach is that you can't conclude $\int_{a} ^{x} F'(t)\, dx=F(x) - F(a) $.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/85481/discussion-between-paramanand-singh-and-user587192).

Comment: @ParamanandSingh: "The issue in your approach is that you can't conclude" Yes, I can. The essential issue is that we have different interpretations of OP's question. I'm talking about $(p\to q)\to r$ and you are talking about $q\not\to r$. I have read your linked follow-up question and Apostol's book as well. Your interpretation is accurate. I'm updating my answer right now.

Comment: In any case there is a downvote (and it does not affect your reputation as the post is wiki) but just to clarify I am not the downvoter.

Comment: You have my upvote. Also thanks for the statement of general theorem from Apostol.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh: thank you for your kind words. I was confused that I failed to see how the counterexample fits in the whole thing. Glad to see what is really going on: I assumed something false at the beginning, and of course, "from falsehood, anything follows"...

Answer (score 2):

You need to understand that a precondition for defining Riemann integral $\int_{a} ^{b} f(x) \, dx$ is that $f$ is defined and bounded on $[a, b] $. Thus for $\int_{a} ^{b} F'(x) \, dx$ to make any sense we must have $F$ differentiable on $[a, b] $ and therefore $F$ is continuous on $[a, b] $ so that continuity is not an assumption but rather an obvious conclusion.

It is rather weird that you have an exercise to show the necessity of this assumption.

---

After your comments to the question, it appears that you are interested in the following question :

> Let $F$ be defined on $[a, b] $ and differentiable on $(a, b) $ such that $F'$ is bounded and continuous on $(a, b) $. Do we necessarily need $F$ to be continuous on $[a, b] $ so that $$\int_{a} ^{b} F'(x) \, dx=F(b) - F(a)? $$

As I mentioned in first part of the answer you need some values of the function $F'$ at $a, b$ before we can make sense of its integral on $[a, b] $. Since the values of a function at a finite number of points does not impact its Riemann integrability or the the value of its integral (if it exists) we may as well consider a function $g:[a, b] \to\mathbb{R} $ such that $g(x) =F'(x) $ for all $x\in(a, b) $ and by the given conditions of $F'$ we see that $g$ is bounded and Riemann integrable on $[a, b] $ and thus the symbol $\int_{a}^{b} F'(x) \, dx$ can be defined as $\int_{a}^{b} g(x) \, dx$.

Let's now consider the function $G:[a, b] \to\mathbb{R} $ defined by $$G(x) =\int_{a} ^{x} g(t) \, dt$$ And then by definition of $G$ we have $G$ continous on $[a, b] $ and further $$\int_{a} ^{b} g(x) \, dx=G(b) - G(a),G'(x)=g(x)=F'(x)\, \forall x\in(a, b) $$ Consider the function $H(x) = F(x) - G(x) $ then $H'(x) =0$ for all $x\in(a, b) $. It follows that $H(x) $ equals some constant on $k$ on $(a, b) $ and thus $$F(x) =G(x) +k\, \forall x\in(a, b) $$ It follows that $$\lim_{x\to a^{+}} F(x) =G(a) +k, \lim_{x\to b^{-}} F(x) =G(b) +k$$ and putting all pieces together we have $$\int_{a} ^{b} F'(x) \, dx=\int_{a} ^{b} g(x) \, dx=G(b) - G(a) =\lim_{x\to b^{-}} F(x) - \lim_{x\to a^{+}} F(x) $$ and thus continuity of $F$ at $a, b$ is not necessary but we only need to pick values $F(a), F(b) $ such that $F(b) - F(a) $ equals the difference between left hand limit of $F$ at $b$ and right hand limit of $F$ at $a$.

I hope this is what you intend to know, but this is not exactly clarified in your question.

---

The argument of my answer can be simplified greatly if one considers a fixed point $c\in(a, b) $ and then note that by FTC we have $$F(x) =F(c) +\int_{c} ^{x} F'(t) \, dt, \,\forall x\in(a, b) $$ Since the integral $\int_{a} ^{b} F'(x) \, dx$ exists it follows by above equation that left (right) hand limit of $F$ at $b$ ($a$) exists and note that the above argument works for not just continuous derivative $F'$ but rather for any derivative $F'$ which is bounded and Riemann integrable.

Comment: it's common to require differentiability only on (a,b), not on [a,b] -- I think that's what is happening here. In particular in my analysis class differentiability at a point x was only defined if the function f was defined on an open neighborhood around x.

Comment: @6005: i am saying that if you wish to talk about $\int_{a} ^{b} F'(x) \, dx$ as a Riemann integral then you must ensure as a precondition that it is defined and bounded in $[a, b] $.

Comment: This seems OK to me and undeserving of a downvote +1.

Comment: @user587192: the idea is that if you take intermediate points then you already know that derivative $F'$ exists at those points and is continuous too. I wanted to examine what happens at the end points of the interval where we don't have any given information.